# Can we generate rails resources dynamically, on the fly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-pattern

I am designing a website builder using rails.

I have following main resources and relationships: a website has many pages, a website has one css _template,  a page has many sections.

There are other attributes for each resources.

At the lowest nesting, I am thinking of dynamically generating resources like buttons, forms, slideshows, api components from other websites all depending on the website category.

My question are:
1. Is this a candidate for factory pattern where i can use a factory to generate the type of resource  ?

2. Can i generate resources and their controllers on the fly?
3. If yes what about a factory pattern for views related to that component ?

How?

Answer (score 1):

You can generate resources on the fly by manipulating the routing data structure, but it's overkill for your use case.

I would make a resource like `resources :badges` in your routes (using `rails g resource Badge`) and then /badges/1 /badges/2 etc will be standard resources tied to the database, which will store an appropriate specification from your CMS authors (e.g. "badge" table might have columns like "label", "color" etc).